# How to poll email from same group mailbox but for different server instances(Ex: Dev,QA,Staging)?

Tags: java, apache-camel, polling, email

I am using Apache Camel Email Polling to read mails from a group mailbox.I am facing a issue in polling the email because I have to use same group mailbox to poll for different Server Instances (For Ex : Dev,QA,Staging).For production, we have a different mailbox configured. But for testing till staging environment , I have to use same group mailbox.

Is there a way to know which server instance has picked up the unread email from Group Mailbox?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to know which server has picked up the message or you want to process messages specific to an environment only. If you want a environment specific processing, I suggest you to use message filters and filter messages based on the "from". I assume the from changes from environment to environment.